# Правильно ли расставлены запятые? - 2

Tags: пунктуация

Маленькая Валерия, ждала свою очередь пофотографироваться и ,совсем невзначай ,выложила из камушек, то чего у неё нет

Comment: Часть Вашего предложения  — "... совсем невзначай, выложила из камушек, то чего у неё нет"  — не очень понятна. Ждем поправок.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Вероятно, имеется в виду мозаика из камушков.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно:

> Маленькая Валерия ждала свою очередь пофотографироваться и совсем невзначай выложила из ***камушков*** то, чего у неё нет.

Answer (score 0):

"Из камушек" - неверно, корректно: "из камушков".

А еще я бы посоветовал заменить "ждала свою очередь" на "ждала своей очереди" (В Нац. корпусе огромное число примеров с "ждала своей очереди" и только один - с "ждала свою очередь".)

**Маленькая Валерия ждала своей очереди пофотографироваться и совсем невзначай выложила из камушков то, чего у неё нет.**

Если автор желает выделить "совсем невзначай", то возможен вариант:

**Маленькая Валерия ждала своей очереди пофотографироваться и – совсем невзначай – выложила из камушков то, чего у неё нет.**